Using CalcPotentialEnergy() function in Drake
Does anybody have experience with using the CalcPotentialEnergy() function in Drake in Python? The documentation provides no example on it.
Thanks!
https://drake.mit.edu/pydrake/pydrake.systems.framework.html?highlight=potential#pydrake.systems.framework.System.CalcPotentialEnergy
I want to calculate the potential energy of an object (lets say a box) with respect to time.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Note: If you have a MultibodyPlant, then CalcPotentialEnergy operates at the level of all bodies in the plant (not just one).
The drake unit tests should always have coverage of every entry point; here is a call to CalcPotentialEnergy from python.
The minimal example using MultibodyPlant would look something like this:
plant = MultibodyPlant(time_step=0.001)
# add your bodies/geometries here... probably using Parser()
plant.Finalize()

context = plant.CreateDefaultContext()
context.SetTime(0.5)
plant.SetPositions(context, [0.1, 0.2, 0.3])
potential_energy = plant.CalcPotentialEnergy(context)

